# Paypal Return URL is not triggering properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Our website has following one time payment buttons.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="@Model.UserId.ToString()">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.testweb.com/paypal/IpnHandler">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.testweb.com/paypal/Onetimeyearlysuccess">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.testweb.com/paypal/cancel">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="8xxxxxxC">
    <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/images/OneTime55year.png")" border="0" name="submit" style="width: 130px !important; height: 47px !important;" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" >
</form>
```

After done the paypal payment, we could see we are getting 404 error.
The issue is that we are getting wrong URL.

https://www.testweb.com/PaypalOnetimeyearlysuccess?amt=55.00&cc=USD&cm=22028&item_name=oneTimeAnnual55&st=Completed&tx=59M0424544743135Y

We don’t know why the slash missing after paypal.

The correct URL should be

https://www.testweb.com/Paypal/Onetimeyearlysuccess?amt=55.00&cc=USD&cm=22028&item_name=oneTimeAnnual55&st=Completed&tx=59M0424544743135Y

There needs to be slash symbol after paypal in the address URL.

You can see the correct URL from the return URL of the paypal button also.

Why it is redirecting to wrong address?

Also for testing purpose,we changed the return URL of the paypal button. We simply modified to “http://www.testweb.com/paypal/Onetimeyearlysuccesstest.”

But we could see after changed the return URL , paypal is not redirecting to modified URL.

Actually we are confused ,we need to know where the return URL is creating.

Comment: Can you share the code which uses these values and performs the PayPal operation?

Comment: Could you add some code samples from your controller? Remember to omit any private keys like API keys

Answer (score 0):

PayPal only recognize the value of 'return' variable. The key point is located at this URL (http://www.testweb.com/paypal/Onetimeyearlysuccess). You are advised to create a fixed single page without redirect function like .html, .php, .aspx, etc., to see the result.